# .validate() show messages JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I wanted to validate each textbox with the validation plugin. But i don't know if im doing this right, I am new in this technology. can someone help me please?

What I wanted to do is everytime I removed the focus in a specific textbox I wanted to show error messages if its invalid and show check "logo" if its valid. I want it to be done in every single textbox.

This is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#valFname").hide();
$("#valLname").hide();


    $('#mainform').validate({
        rules: {
            fname: {
                required: true,
            },
            lname: {
                required: true,
            },
            captcha: {
                equalTo:"#key"
            }
        },
        success: function () {
            fname:
            {
                required: $("#valFname").show();
            },
            lname:
            {
                required: $("#valLname").show();
            }
        }

    });
    $('#btnSignUp').click(function () {

    });
});
```

This is my markup

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="loginBouncy.js"></script>
<script src="modal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
<script src="validate.js"></script>
<div id='mask' class='close_modal'></div>

<div id="signup" class='modal_window'>
<p id="summary"></p>


<img id="pane1" src="pane1.png"/>
<p id="label">SignUp</p>
<p id="label1">Personal&nbsp;Information</p>
<p id="label2">Account</p>
<p id="label3">Verification</p>
<hr id="hr1"/>
<form id="mainform" name="mainform" method="post" action="SignUp2.php">

<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["code"] = md5(uniqid());
$_SESSION["key"] = substr($_SESSION["code"],0,5);
$key = $_SESSION["key"];

echo "<input style='z-index:12;' type='hidden' name='key' id='key' value='$key'/>";
?>

<img id="valFname" style="position:absolute; top:257px; z-index:20; left:835px;" src="valid.png"/><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name"/>
<img id="valLname" style="position:absolute; top:257px; z-index:20; left:1045px;" src="valid.png"/><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name"/>
<input type="text" id="mname" name="mname" placeholder="M.I."/>
<input type="text" id="sadd"  name="sadd" placeholder="Street"/>
<input type="text" id="tadd"  name="tadd" placeholder="Town/City"/>
<input type="text" id="padd"  name="padd" placeholder="Province/State"/>
<input type="text" id="user2" name="user2" placeholder="Your Username"/>
<input type="password"  id="pass2" name="pass2" placeholder="Your Password">
<input id="captcha" name="captcha" type="text" placeholder="Insert Captcha">
<img id="imgcaptcha" src="captcha.php" /><br>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email"/>
<input type="submit" id="btnSignUp"  value=""  />
</input>

</form>





</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show your markup and/or set up a demo? What does the code do now?

Comment: Could you please add the HTML code too? And it would be great if you could create a JSFiddle too

Comment: your success callback is invalid javascript...

Comment: is there any solution for that?